# Bloom Filter Response Processing In terms of Full-node

Tags: full-node, spv, query

A SPV node have to work somethings to see whether his transaction is exist or not.

1. Construct his filter with hash of transactions {his transactions, other1, other2, ..., otherN}
2. `filterload` is filled to process his filter by full-node (by BIP-0037)
3. Send to full-nodes

Okay, these are responsible for SPV node and let me take a view of full-node received the filter.

1. Lookup chain to find **transaction(K)** with `filterload`

What...? hold on.. how can the full-node know that **transaction(K)** is what? `filterload` has no any information of **transactions(K)**. 
`filterload` = { filter, nHashFuncs, nTweak, nFalgs } 
Nobody doesn't explain about this in the web, including BIP-0037. Just explains only what is a bloom filter.
I think that full-node must know what transactions(K) are to find on his ledger, otherwise full-node have to see entire chain and this doesn't make sense.

So.. I'd like to know the proper procedure on full-node received the filter by SPV node.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: bip37 is disabled in new releases so you shouldn’t build anything based on it.

Comment: I read some articles about your reply. Isn't disabling BIP37 optional, not required?

Comment: It’s default off and will likely be removed entirely in the future.

Comment: So, what is an alternative instead Bloom Filter?